# How to change election type in kingdom of scotland

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm currently king of Ireland and Scotland, and own about half of GB. One of my relatives got a claim on the Kingdom of England, so I managed to win that war and place my cousin on the throne of England. Having done this, now I'm trying to combine all three kingdoms.

I tried using elective monarchy, this works good in Ireland, because here only dukes can vote on a successor and I have only granted 1 person a duchy. However, in Scotland all the vassals can vote, including my counts. They keep electing random dudes and my question is how I can change this to the way my Irish elective works. I have selected minimal crown authority in both kingdoms.

Comment: I edited your second Ireland to Scotland, please edit if that is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

One of your Kingdoms is currently using Tanistry succession. This allows everyone up to two ranks below you (for a kingdom, counts and above), but only dynasty members are eligible.

To change the laws, go to the Laws page, select the kingdom you want to change by clicking its coat of arms and select the new law. Note that you can only change laws if:

- You are at peace
- You have held that title for at least 10 years
- None of your count+ vassals have a negative opinion of you
- None of your vassals are fighting each other (this can be difficult with Low Crown Authority)
- You haven't changed that kingdom's crown authority before

If all of these are true, you will be able to change Scotland to Elective. Note that this **doesn't** guarantee the same character will win both elections.

If you want to ensure both kingdoms go to the same person, destroy the Kingdom of Scotland Title. To do this, select the title from your character view or the find title menu and click destroy. This will cost prestige and will anger your vassals in Scotland (-50 opinion) but having a single kingdom is stronger in the long run.

Comment: If anyone has a problem with my answer, let me know. If you can't write, post an image that shows your feelings or something.

Comment: Answer looks fine to me. Perhaps down voter hates elective succession.

Comment: @PaulRichter At least it's not gavelkind.